# Error with jQuery load function in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have this problem, when I load /index.php?route=quickcheckout/checkout with jQuery function load it's load perfectly in FF in IE and sometimes even in Chrome.

But sometimes in Chrome it doesn't load content from /index.php?route=quickcheckout/checkout but load the page you are on in div with id blagajna.

Here is my code for this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".img-thumbnail").click(function () {
    $(this).prev('input:radio').prop('checked', true);
});
$('form').on('click', '.img-thumbnail', function() {
        var url = "/index.php?route=checkout/cart/add";
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: $("#oko").serialize(),
               async: false,
               success: function(data)
               {
                $('input:radio').prop('checked', false);
                $(".izbira").hide();
                $(".dodano").show().delay(1500).fadeOut();
                $("#blagajna").load( "/index.php?route=quickcheckout/checkout" );
               }
             });

        return false;
});
</script>
```

and this is URL: http://trgagate.si/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=50#narocilo

Problem appears only in Chrome when you click on some bottle in order form.

Thanks for help.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: a(...).live is not a function` Someone is using a library that relies on an old version of jQuery which you are not using.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to be generated in a file that is returning some script

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $('.colorbox').colorbox({
         width: 640,
         height: 480
    });
//--></script>
```

colorbox is calling the live() function which may be deprecated. If you have access to the jquery.colorbox-min.js file just do a find+replace and change all references of "live" to "on"

Comment: alternatively, look on the internet to see if there is an updated version of colorbox